# How to limit CPU cycles and memory on a python process

Tags: python, python-3.x, process

I want to run a simple python server, which will take python code as a string input. And I need to run the input string using `eval()` or with `exec()` in python. (In the sample code below, i haven't added the `eval()` part yet, it will go inside `task()`)

But i'm looking a way to restrict each user by providing 1% CPU and may be 1% memory. I have tried resources package (https://docs.python.org/3/library/resource.html). Which seems to set the limits for the whole python code (not just for the process i'm running)

Here is what I have tried as a POC. If you have good suggestions let me know. Thank you

```
def task():
    soft, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS)
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (1024, hard))
    s = "helloworld"
    for j in range(1, 10):
        s = s + s        
    print("Executors in process {}", format(os.getpid()))

def main():
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
    task1 = executor.submit(task)
    task2 = executor.submit(task)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(1, 10):
        main()
```

Comment: on Linux you can run program with `cpulimit -l 1 program` and then you could write code in file and run `cpulimit -l 1 python script.py`

Comment: maybe you should use `multiprocessing` to run code in separated processes and then maybe `resource.setrlimit` will work only with Python in this process.